# In executing code block in org-mode, how to use result of different code block, where result is a file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

So, I need to pass the content of one Org source block into another.

There are a couple of ways. One can use :noweb header and reference content in the second block using `<<first-block-content>>`. Or you can use `:var` header, but then you have to keep the first block as `#+begin_example`, not `#+begin_src`.

My problem is a bit different. I want to refer to the content of the first block as a filename. E.g.,

```
#+name: block-1
#+begin_src json :tangle "some-file.json"
{"example": "example json"}
#+end_src

#+begin_src sh 
cat some-file.json | jq
#+end_src
```

And this kinda works, right? Except, there's one caveat that's bugging me. You still have to manually tangle the file from the first block. And I want to find a way to avoid that. Whenever I eval the second block, I want it to automatically find the first block, tangle its file, and only after that eval the second block. And I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `:results file` in the first block, and then by using the result of block-1 in your second block via `:var in=block-1 (where you simply discard the result), you can trigger execution of block-1 'from' your second block, e.g:

```
#+name: block-1
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results file silent :file some-file.el
'(:example "example json")
#+end_src

#+begin_src sh :var input=block-1
cat some-file.el
#+end_src
```

Comment: You can do a bit better: don't silence the results from the first block and use `$input` in the shell command in the second block. That loosens the tight coupling between the two blocks a bit.

Comment: That's a nice comment indeed. I noticed that it is not necessary to remove the `silent` from the first code block.

Comment: Ah right:`silent` is only for the benefit/detriment of human eyes :-) As a minot point, note that if you execute the second block, it runs the first block but it does not insert the output in the buffer (silent or not).